# State not updated after successful AJAX request

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I'm doing a basic React app with data coming from my api. But the state is not updated when I do `this.setState({})` after AJAX success. The state.events is empty in the `render` method.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            events: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/events')
            .then(function (response) {
                this.setState({events: response.data});
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.warn(error);
            });
    }

    render() {    
        // this.state.events keeps being an empty array []
        return (
            <div className="home">
              {
                this.state.events.map((month) => {
                  console.log(month) 
                })
              }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are using should throw the error, check the `console`. You need to `bind` the context to use `this` keyword inside callback method that you are using in `.then`, Use this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/events')
        .then( response => {
            console.log('data', response.data);
            this.setState({events: response.data});
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.warn(error);
        });
}
```

or use `.bind(this)` to bind the context, like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/events')
        .then(function (response) {
            this.setState({events: response.data});
        }.bind(this))
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.warn(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: OMG thanks, I forgot the classic 'this confusion' in JS :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind axios success function to the correct context to make use  of setState. USe this

```
componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/events')
            .then(function (response) {
                this.setState({events: response.data});
            },bind(this))
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.warn(error);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this
```

inside callback doesn't refer to your component context for that you need to bind your callback function of axios with your react component to update state of that component

```
import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        events: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/events')
        .then(function (response) {
            this.setState({events: response.data});
        }.bind(this)) // binding of callback to component
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.warn(error);
        });
}

render() {    
    // this.state.events keeps being an empty array []
    return (
        <div className="home">
          {
            this.state.events.map((month) => {
              console.log(month) 
            })
          }
        </div>
    );
}
```

}